# Set Sierra modem to packet switching via AT Command using ubuntu live CD

Tags: ubuntu, modem, at, ttyusb

- Lifebook E5440 has WWAN Modem Sierra EM8805
- Multi SIM - Phone is occupied when Notebook is online
  *i know this problem from lenovo notebooks*
- Win10 doesnt let me set the config cause there is no com port

i used this workaround before

- boot ubuntu lice cd
- 2 terminals

  ```
  sudo su
  cat /dev/ttyUSB0
  ```

second terminal

```
    sudo su
    echo "AT^SYSCFGEX?" > /dev/ttyUSB0
    echo 'AT^SYSCFGEX="00",3FFFFFFF,1,1,7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF,,' > /dev/ttyUSB0
```

1. Problem: I dont have /dev/ttyUSB0 on Fujitsu Notebook
2. Problem: I guessed by googling /dev/cdc-wdm0 is the modem - but when i CAT device i get gibberish
3. cant run the AT command nor other ones like

   ```
    AT!STKVER
   ```

   - Do i have to setup a tty? How?
   - If not how to find correct tty?
   - Are AT command equal for every vendor?
   - How to enable packet switching for sierra em8805 via ubuntu?

UPDATE

Seems Sierra Modem is PW protected, got command reference from sierra.com - no luck so far with